# Play Store Beta Testing, Android Keystore, and Hired Developer

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, android-keystore

So I have several "**issues**".

I hired a developer for my apps, and he needs live access **Play Store Alpha / Beta testing**. We are testing **In-App purchasing**, and it cannot be tested on device.

I granted him permission (from dev console) to access **Alpha/Beta** sections. One thing I don't want to give him is my Keystore / Signing key, along with my password.

Play Store wants **APK** signed with original key for **Beta** testing (or do they?)

So how do I go about it?

And another question - how do teams with multiple devs deal with these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to give him the keys you have these options:

1. You need to build and sign every single apk he wants to upload to google play.
2. Set up a build server like jenkins and let jenkins build + sign on every git push. Then make the resulting signed apk available to the team.
3. Create some internal signing service where developers can submit an apk file and get it back signed.

Comment: I like the second option - Can you explain this in more details: _Set up a build server like jenkins and let jenkins build + sign on every git push. Then make the resulting signed apk available to the team._

Comment: Well, I use jenkins: http://jenkins-ci.org/ it's quite easy to set up. Install it, install plugins for android (and gradle), create a job based on or gradle, set up periodic git pull or trigger jenkins on every git push via api.

Comment: Checkout GitLab.com, for a small scale project you can integrate continuous integration with just a few lines of code. You can your developer to pick keystore path and passwords from EVN variables. And then configure your production variables on your gitlab console. It's free and saves you the time required to setup Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more recent (2023, 10 years later) avenue with [GitLab 15.11](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/04/22/gitlab-15-11-released/#google-play-store-integration) (April 2023):

> ### Google Play Store integration
>
> From GitLab 15.11, you can configure and validate your projects with Google Play Store credentials.
> You can then use those credentials in CI/CD pipelines to automate releases to the Google Play Store.
>
> To record your experiences with the Google Play Store integration, see this [feedback issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/feedback/-/issues/13).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/google_play.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/incubation-engineering/mobile-devops/readme/-/issues/35).